# How many ways are there to select a pair of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

A standard deck of cards contains 52 cards: 13 cards each of 4 different “suits”, hearts (red),
diamonds (red), spades (black) and clubs (black).

B) How many ways are there to select a pair of cards from a standard deck of cards such that
one of the cards is red and the other one is black? Your answer can contain factorial or
power expressions. Explain your answer.

My answer: to select a red card, we have to choose 13 red cards out of 52 cards. one red can be chosen from 13 cards in 13 ways. for each of these 13 ways, one black card can be chosen in 13 ways. therefor a total number of ways is 13*13= 169.

but my friend says it is 52*26. Could anyone confirm who has the right answer?

Comment: There are $26$ red cards in total and $26$ black cards in total.  Now... we need to clarify whether or not we treat order as mattering... for example whether $5\heartsuit J\spadesuit$ counts as the same "pair of cards" as $J\spadesuit 5\heartsuit$.  If they count as the same, the total will be $26\times 26$.  If they don't count as the same then it will be $2\times 26\times 26 = 52\times 26$, the times two as a result of picking the order... be it black then red, or red then black.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you have never seen a deck of cards before if you made the mistake of thinking there are only $13$ red cards instead of $26$.  Perhaps look at [pictures like this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:English_pattern_playing_cards_deck.svg).

Comment: @JMoravitz: It's [not that simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-color_deck)!

Comment: @TonyK it is when they question very clearly specified "*hearts (red), diamonds (red), spades (black) and clubs (black)*"